# Electron theory origin

Tags: electricity

A body having mass and velocity exerts force in the direction of velocity .we know that electron has both mass and velocity. Then why electric force(electric current) flows in opposite direction of flow electrons.as in cathode ray experiment
I mean that why current flows in opp direction to that of kinetic energy

Comment: The electric force responsible for the flow of electrons in a wire is generally due to the electric force created by the terminals of a battery which are maintained at a potential.

Comment: -1. It is not clear to me what you are asking. There are several ideas jumbled together here - momentum, mechanical force, electric force (electro-motive force?), electric current, cathode rays. The jumble doesn't make sense, and it is not clear how any of it relates to your title, which only adds to the puzzle.

Comment: Bhaiya i was asking that why electric force is in opposite in direction to that of motion of the electron

Comment: Without proper punctuation, it is hard to decipher what it is you are asking. Please edit this to put punctuation marks and clean up some of the grammar as well.

Answer (score 1):

> I mean that why current flows in opp direction to that of kinetic energy

It is a matter of conventional definition. Currents and charges were defined before the [discovery of the electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode_ray#Discovery_of_the_electron)

> [A flow of positive charges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current#Conventions) gives the same electric current, and has the same effect in a circuit, as an equal flow of negative charges in the opposite direction. Since current can be the flow of either positive or negative charges, or both, a convention is needed for the direction of current that is independent of the type of charge carriers. The direction of conventional current is arbitrarily defined as the same direction as positive charges flow.

[image: current]  [image]The symbol for a battery in a circuit diagram.

> The electrons, the charge carriers in an electrical circuit, flow in the opposite direction of the conventional electric current.

[Here is the electric](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/pplate.html) field in a capacitor conventionally:

[image: capacitor E]

By convention the electron will move against the direction of the [electric field.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elefie.html) The force on an electron will be

[image: force]

For B=0, the electric field is multiplied with the (-) charge of the electron, so the force IS in the direction of motion of the electron, from negative to positive.

It is all a matter of conventions.